# SQL combine rows to be able to filter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, filter

I want to combine some rows, so I can filter the customers properly.

```
 SELECT
 StammIndex
, sPropSet
, bProp01
  FROM [Properties] as properties
  RIGHT JOIN [Kunden] as kunden
  ON Kunden.StammIndex = properties.KundenIndex
```

[image: Currently my Database]

"StammIndex" is the customers ID,

"sPropSet" is the property and

"bProp01" tells you if the property is checked (1) or not checked (0)

The problem is, that customers that have checked the property at least once are saved in the Database.
That means, that the customer IDs will be saved multiple times.

Now I want to get all customers, that didn't check the "Serienbrief" property.

```
SELECT
 StammIndex
, sPropSet
, bProp01
  FROM [Properties] as properties
  RIGHT JOIN [Kunden] as kunden
  ON Kunden.StammIndex = properties.KundenIndex 
  WHERE NOT (sPropSet = 'Serienbrief' AND bProp01 = 1) OR sPropSet IS NULL
```

[image: How far I got]

Here you can see that customer '10001' is still there, because he got two properties. I want customer '10001' removed too, because he also got the property "Serienbrief" checked.

First post on stackoverflow, so sorry if I didn't explain my problem properly.
If you got any further questions, please feel free to ask.

EDIT*

My Filter is in C#. The Code behind looks like this

```
 internal class FilterEigenschaften
    {
        public static List<UndBlock> FilterEigenschaftenListe = new List<UndBlock>();

        public List<AdressenListe> Filter(Connection conn)
        {
            Criteria undBlockCriteria = conn.CreateCriteria();

            foreach (UndBlock undBlock in FilterEigenschaften.FilterEigenschaftenListe)
            {
                Criteria oderBlockCriteria = conn.CreateCriteria();
                foreach (OderBlock oderBlock in undBlock.OderBlock)
                {
                    Criteria filterBlockCriteria = conn.CreateCriteria();
                    foreach (FilterBlock filterBlock in oderBlock.FilterBlock.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Wert)))
                    {
                        filterBlockCriteria.AddAnd("sPropSet", Operator.Equal, filterBlock.Kriterium);
                        filterBlockCriteria.AddAnd("bProp" + this.FiterSqlEigenschaftenFelder(conn, filterBlock), Operator.Equal, 1);
                        if (filterBlock.Operand == "Ist markiert")
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    oderBlockCriteria.AddOr(filterBlockCriteria);
                }

                undBlockCriteria.AddAnd(oderBlockCriteria);
            }

            string cmdText = $"SELECT Distinct(Kunde.StammIndex) " +
                             $"FROM {conn.Tablenames[4]} AS Kunde " +
                             $"RIGHT JOIN {conn.Tablenames[12]} AS Properties " +
                             $"ON Kunde.StammIndex = Properties.KundenIndex " +
                             $"WHERE {undBlockCriteria}";

            return WordSqlAdressen.GetAdressenListe(conn, cmdText);
        }

        private string FiterSqlEigenschaftenFelder(Connection conn, FilterBlock filterBlock)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
            {
                using (Command cmd = conn.CreateCommand($"SELECT sProp{i:00} " +
                $"FROM {conn.Tablenames[13]} " +
                $"WHERE sPropSet = '{filterBlock.Kriterium}'"))
                {
                    using (DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReaderEx())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            if (dr.GetString((0)) == filterBlock.Wert)
                            {
                                return i.ToString("00");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

I can only use one SQL statement to see, if the property is checked or not checked

Comment: (1) Put your query in your question as *text* not an image.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) You show sample data from one "table", but your query references multiple tables.  I'm confused.

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: What's the schema for [Kunden]?

Comment: The [Kunden] Database has all customers in it, with their Data

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move your condition to your join rather than the where clause.

I.e.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Kuden k
LEFT JOIN Properties p
  ON k.StammIndex = p.KudenIndex
  AND p.sPropSet = 'Serienbrief'
  AND p.bProp01 = 1
WHERE p.KudenIndex IS NULL;
```

Comment: The reason is because putting the condition in the where will change the left join to an inner join.

Comment: Mhhh, with the checked(1) statment it works, but with unchecked(0) statement it doesn't work. If I now change the 1 into a 0 it would get me all IDs, except '10003'

Comment: True.  The query returns "All Kuden without the Serienbrief property checked".  Is that not the information you are looking for?

Comment: I have a multiple filter, that means the user can ask for property "Serienbrief" checked and property "Test" not checked 
so i have to use only one main statment

Comment: That isn't compatible with the way you're storing your data.  As you pointed out, you may have instance of a property being both checked and unchecked for the same user.  Rather than solving this problem with SQL, I think you should ensure that each property can only exist once.